# jquery autocomplete - selected value disappears from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have written a custom jquery autocomplete function to display certain values and textfields to update on selecting the value as per the code below:

```
<input type="text" name="promoitem" id="promoitem">

$('#promoitem').autocomplete({
        source: "BckProcesses/GetPromoItems.asp",
        create: function() {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                .append('<a>' + item.promodesc + '</a>')
                .appendTo(ul);
            }
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#promoitem').val(ui.item.promodesc); 
            $('#promocost').val(ui.item.promocost);
            $('#promoqty').val(ui.item.qty);
            $('#hidden_promo_item_id').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
```

This is what is return by the source file (GetPromoItems.asp)

```
[{"id": "1", "promodesc": "Ipad 4 ", "promocost": "200", "qty": "1"},{"id": "2", "promodesc": "Village Tickets", "promocost": "20", "qty": "2"}]
```

However, when I select the value from the ul, everything gets populated except the promoitem textfield. That fields goes to being blank.

Can anyone please let me know what could be causing this?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're providing your own logic in the `select` handler, you need to prevent the default action, which is to place `ui.item.value` in the `input`.

Right now, your code is running, and then jQueryUI is immediately trying to place `ui.item.value` in the `input`, which explains the empty value.

So really all you need to do is call `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` from the `select` handler:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#promoitem').val(ui.item.promodesc); 
    $('#promocost').val(ui.item.promocost);
    $('#promoqty').val(ui.item.qty);
    $('#hidden_promo_item_id').val(ui.item.id);

    event.preventDefault(); // <---
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. that did work. I thought that by overwriting, it would have taken care of the default :)

Answer (score 0):

After spending an hour, finally got to an point that Jquery UI autocomplete sets the value to default.

Only one line needs to put and prevent Jquery default function to get the wok done.

// pincode list autocomplete

```
$('input[name=\'pincode\']').autocomplete({
        'source': function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=seller/pincode/pincodeAutocomplete&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'pincode\']').val()),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    json.unshift({
                        pincode_id: '',
                        pincode: '-- None --'
                    });
                    response($.map(json, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item['pincode'],
                            value: item['pincode_id']
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        'select': function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('input[name=\'pincode\']').val(ui.item.label);
            $('input[name=\'pincode_id\']').val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```